# Show that the X is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. We assume $X=A\cup B$, with both of the sets non empty, $A \cap B=\emptyset$. A contains non of B's limit points and B contains non of A's limit points. Show that X is disconnected.

I thought I wanted to show that the sets A and B are both open but I have some theorem that says if a set contains all it´s limit points it´s closed. But I dont know how to show that X is disconnected if A and B are closed.

So if anyone knows how to do that or if I´m missing somethig it would help alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are closed and they are complementary $A$ and $B$ are also open sets and you have what do you look for.

Comment: I think they are. Indeed $A$ contains all the limits of its convergence sequences. The same for $B$

Comment: Yep, sorry. I generalized the problem too much. If we had $Y\subseteq A\cup B$ and  the remaining conditions, one could as well conclude that $Y$ is disconnected, without $A,B$ *themselves* being closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The sets $X\setminus \overline A$ and $X\setminus \overline B$ are open.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that $\overline{B}\subseteq B$, where $\overline{B}$ is the closure of $B$. Similarly we have $\overline{A}\subseteq A$. Therefore both $A$ and $B$ are closed.